# Can't save more than one document in GridFS (with MongoMapper/Joint)

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper, padrino, gridfs

I've written a Padrino application that allows you to upload files. It uses MongoMapper (via Joint) to store these files (images) in GridFS. I am able to store one file with no problems. However, when I go to store another file, it saves, but it is not in the database. I wrote specs to use the model class directly (without going through Padrino routes) and I get the same result. What am I doing wrong here?

Gist with related files: https://gist.github.com/1341836

The application: http://github.com/eturk/fhsclock

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in Firefox (instead of Chrome), and it worked. Cleared my cookies and cache in Chrome and it worked. Doh!